# What's the argument against complex type hinting in interfaces in PHP?

Tags: php, data-structures, interfaces

The more I write OOP, the more I realize that besides reasoning & structure, there isn't much for me and things make more sense if I combine that with functional or just straight-up non-OOP. Not over-engineering  is truly a blessing when working with large code-bases and in that case, your **#1 goal should be to create clear & reliable code.** My issue ties to both of these traits.

Assume I had an `IngestedInterface` which objects I'm working with need to implement so that my system can understand them:

```
interface IngestedInterface
{
    public function getData() : string;
}
```

Then, assume I had an ingester object `A` who worked with `IngestedInterface` \ `B` objects' `getData`:

```
class Ingester
{
    public function __construct( IngestedInterface $ingested )
    {
        $this->ingested = $ingested;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $data = $this->ingested->getData();
    }
}
```

We can be 100% sure that `$data` is a `string`. But the situation gets muddy when dealing with PHP's most popular feature: arrays. Assume my `doSomething` changed to:

```
public function doSomething()
{
    $data = $this->ingested->getData();

    return [ $data['some_key_1'], $data['some_key_2'] ];
}
```

We implicitly rely on `some_key_1\2` being returned from `getData` and depending on what you do with them, that they're of a certain type as well. If they're not, the script crashes since it's looking for a key it cannot find and we've just created unreliable, unpredictable code.

There should be a newer, improved interface type that supports complex return types such that expressing a minimally viable (meaning you need these at the very least, but can add on top) array structure to return is possible:

```
interface IngestedInterface
{
    public function getData() : ['some_key_1' => <int|string>, 'some_key_2' => <string>]
}
```

This way, it naturally tells whoever wishes to build upon this `IngestedInterface` that they need to have a complex return for `getData`. **I perfectly understand that I can just have 2 functions for each one of these and just use simple return types, but it makes absolutely 0 sense to separate two things (`some_key1\2`) that are closely related to each other and this case is very common. This is not what I'm looking for here.**

Why do I want this? Because I don't wanna write an `array_key_exists` and an `is_%scalar_type%` for each god-damn possible k\v pair inside an array, in fact, ensuring that an array I'm working with has the right structure oftentimes implies even more checks, all of which could be easily solved with a complex return type.

So, what am I missing? Is this not a desired feature? It'd be a game-changer for me. I write extremely sensitive code that I, unfortunately, have to interface to WordPress infrastructure which runs on PHP and every time and API/endpoint is written, I want to shed a tear since I know that if a client's developer who uses our API feeds the wrong thing, they'll break a lot of things if these checks weren't in place, it's like it gets sour even before I start writing code knowing that I'll have to write these checks for mission-critical endpoints. In other words, can I just write code that's resistant to such issues by default instead of spending my time doing data validation and why don't we have this already?

I don't think anyone capable of directing the core development of a language is stupid, but I can't seem to come up with an argument against this.

Comment: Based on your comments under my question, your question lacks clarity (and on top of that includes profanities). Because of that, I am voting to close this question unless clearer explanation of what you actually need and how the current design is limiting you (what is your relationship to the interface,...) is provided.

Comment: @Andy How can this not be clear? I've stated my issue, stated exactly how the issue manifests itself, stated my desire and exactly where it breaks and why it breaks. Do people just have an inner engine that goes awry when someone says "give me an argument?". Sorry, I thought I was asking about software engineering, not subtleties of syntax that don't really help anyone.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comments. Either way, your attitude is not nice and not suitable for this site. Please, do change your question not to include profanities. Thank you.

Comment: @Andy Removed profanities. My attitude is fine given I was 15k reputation on my other account because I don't store login details. It's just that you're higher ranking and I'm lower-ranking such that behaviors that you'd forgive from someone else (due to you standing to lose something) don't fly with me. Funny how humans operate, don't you think?

Comment: Account score has nothing to do with the approach I am taking. And it saddens me you believe that local moderators would be more hesitant to take action against a question or an answer which does not follow local guidelines should it be posted by an account with 15k points, than when it should be posted by a new account. Because from my experience, that's definitely not the case. The SE boards are basically a Wikipedia these days, therefore the posts must adhere to certain rules, no matter who posts them. I am not going to attempt to reply to any further comment discussing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Returning maps (key-value stores) from non-private methods (in PHP arrays are implemented as [hash tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350361/how-is-the-php-array-implemented-on-the-c-level)), should the returned map represent a complex object, is really not a good idea in ANY language, not only in PHP.

On a `private` level, where the scope of the type is limited to a given `class`, this is acceptable to a certain degree, although even then it's usually better to introduce a specialised type to represent the complex data.

A different situation is when the map actually represents an indexed collection, e.g. a `Map<String, User>` of users indexed by their `string` identifiers. In such case returning a map is fine.

Your issue is then easily solved by introducing a new `class`, which represents to returned data:

```
class IngestedData
{
    /** @var int|string */
    private $someKey1;
    private string $someKey2;

    public function __construct($someKey1, string $someKey2)
    {
        $this->someKey1 = $someKey1;
        $this->someKey2 = $someKey2;
    }

    /** @return int|string */
    public function getSomeKey1()
    {
        return $this->someKey1;
    }

    public function getSomeKey2(): string
    {
        return $this->someKey2;
    }
}
```

which you then use as a return type for your interface:

```
interface IngestedInterface
{
    public function getData(): IngestedData
}
```

Know that up until PHP8.0 release, the mixed type can only be represented through a PhpDoc:

```
/** @var int|string */
private $someKey1
```

however [PHP8.0 introduces Union Types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2), therefore specifying mixed type will be possible as a type hint:

```
private int|string $someKey1;
```

When an array is returned from a non-private method, it's a good practice for the array to be considered a collection of elements of the same type, e.g. an array of **int**egers: `int[]`, **string**s: `string[]`, **SomeComplexObject**s: `SomeComplexObject[]`, etc.

---

> For example, you say that *returning complex maps is never a good
> idea", I've asked before and I'm asking again, because that's a
> potential answer as to why some of the core contributors might've just
> said no to even proposing an RFC towards this and as such, it fits the
> direct "what is an argument against complex type hinting".

When you do want to return a complex map which actually represents a structural object, i.e. map's keys are names of properties and values are their values a structural object should be used. That's why structures were introduced, to give complex types better meaning.

Consider a situation where you would like to return the data you're asking about:

- `some_key_1` --> `int|string`,
- `some_key_2` --> `string`,

in Java or a similar strongly typed language. The only way how to do this would be to return a `Map<String, Object>` from a method, otherwise you'd get a compilation error. And having a `Map<String, Object>` instance is not helpful at all, it tells you nothing about actual types, about available keys, it's a mess.

> Because complex type hinting or type hinting, in general, is simply
> just very tasty flavor for data validation. I don't see why type
> hinting string in interfaces is alright, but not the structure of an
> array. Yes, they're different, but what's the issue here?

As I have said above, advanced array type hinting was not introduced because it's not an elegant code. There are better constructs (actual structures) to represent the same thing.

> First question: IngestedData's children (classes that extend it)
> cannot be changed by me, no. I simply just ingest it and work with it.
> Second question: I'm trying to understand the motivation behind not
> supporting something that'd solve my issue, given it is a real issue,
> in other words, I'd like an architectural overview/motivation behind
> the ifs/whys of the issue at hand.

What you're actually after is an anti-corruption layer. That is a layer which hides ugly implementation details of 3rd party libraries (in our theoretical case the `IngestedData` children, or the structured array), converts them to structures you know ([Adapters and Adaptees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)), and are an author of, and you are able to change, and then your code uses these adapted objects instead of the ugly interface a 3rd party library may provide.

This has some benefits, I am going to name few:

- your core code is decoupled from the third party library,
- you can prepare adapters for the third party interface to only include the details you're actually interested in and ignore the rest,
- should the API of the third party library change and you need to adapt your code, this change is isolated only to your adaptation layer and you probably won't need to touch your core code at all.

Comment: I have to ask, because it's still not clear since you didn't explain it past "it's just not good"...what is that one case where returning a complex type creates issues? I am solely interested in code that exemplifies an issue/solution. Also, the class solution is, at least for me, just not good - I can't control `IngestedData`'s extended class (child) flow at all and nor do I want to. I just want a simple contract that objects abide to.

Comment: Additionally, using this class simply doesn't provide any runtime checks as type hinting does. It's more of a guidelines list rather than the code actually breaking if the contract is broken.

Comment: @DanielSimmons *[...] Also, the class solution is, at least for me, just not good - I can't control IngestedData's extended class (child) flow at all and nor do I want to. [...]* I don't understand. Who's responsible for the interface? Are you the creator, or are you simply consuming it and therefore cannot be changed by you?

Comment: @DanielSimmons *[...] this class simply doesn't provide any runtime checks as type hinting does [...]* Your proposed solution does not solve it either. The class solution in PHP < 8.0 does not check against the proposed `int|string` combination (which is only present in the PhpDoc), but it does guard you against passing a non-string to `$someKey2`. After the release of PHP 8.0 and migration to it, you're even protected against the first case.

Comment: First question: `IngestedData`'s children (classes that extend it) cannot be changed by me, no. I simply just ingest it and work with it. Second question: I'm trying to understand the motivation behind not supporting something that'd solve my issue, given it is a real issue, in other words, I'd like an architectural overview/motivation behind the ifs/whys of the issue at hand.

Comment: For example, you say that *returning complex maps is never a good idea", I've asked before and I'm asking again, because that's a potential answer as to why some of the core contributors might've just said no to even proposing an RFC towards this and as such, it fits the direct "what is an argument against complex type hinting".

Comment: Because complex type hinting or type hinting, in general, is simply just very tasty flavor for data validation. I don't see why type hinting `string` in interfaces is alright, but not the structure of an array. Yes, they're different, but what's the issue here?